# Save Custom Objects in Cocos2d-x

Tags: object, save, cocos2d-x

I'm not sure if this would be possible using sqlite or some other method of saving, but how would one save a custom object in a cocos2d-x game? Can you serialize it and store in the an sqlite database and then unserialize when you want to read the data? Is that efficient enough?

I'm looking for pointers on how to do this. I created a game using Sprite Kit and saving using the NSCoding protocol which was very nice. Not sure if there is something similar in Cocos2d-x, but doesn't look like it. Anyways, any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you really want to save the "object", I think serialization is the route. If what you really mean is saving game data between playing there is `UserDefaults` and/or SQLite. I personally use SQLite in my games.

Comment: It's `UserDefault`. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/db/d94/classcocos2d_1_1_user_default.html